# CRT AND WIN32 API

Tags: c++, c, windows

hI,

I'm wondering under windows where the CRT lib is used. In each dll forming the win32 API? Only by software developped under visual studio ?

In other words, is Windows OS perform malloc, write/read on files and so on, by using other thing than CRT?

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C runtime (in case of Visual Studio 2010 msvcr100.dll) contains the implementation of the C standard library functions.

The C runtime is implemented in a platform-specific way, and in the Windows case, it uses functions from kernel32.dll (part of the Win32 API) to perform its tasks.

You can have a look at the exported and imported functions and DLL dependencies using [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you wanted to ask in your first question. About the second though: CRT is not windows-specific but VS-specific. Your C programs that you compile with VS will use the MSVCRTxx DLLs to provide (most) C library functions. In turn, the C library functions will use the WINAPI to do actual stuff. The WINAPI is the last layer that talks to the OS.

Other compilers, such as g++ in MINGW will not use the MSVCRTxx DLLs but have their own. In the end, that will also use the WINAPI. For example, `malloc` will most likely call [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in any implementation.

Comment: Ok but in case of a C++ soft developped under VS, why CRT is still required ? Why implementation of new for instance doesn't use directly the win32 API and VirtualAlloc ?

Comment: the implementation of new does call VirtualAlloc. The implementation of new is contained in the runtime.

Comment: so it was a mistake of me to say that a c++ software is linking with the CRT ?